# Launch callback from jquery function Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a jquery plugin installed in my Nuxt.js app. I'm using it in a Vue template :

```
methods:{
            onScriptLoaded: async function(event = null) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                  window.jQuery('#widget').pluginOpen({
                      "URL" : " https://myapi.com",
                      "callBackFrame": 'callBackFrame'
                  });
                },500);
            }
```

Where can I write the callback function ? I tried to declare another method, but the script doesn't find it.

Thanks

Comment: What are pluginOpen and callBackFrame and why are using jQuery? It shouldn't be used with modern frameworks like Vue.

Comment: It uses jQuery because the plugin was only available in jQuery, I had to import it in my Vue template

Comment: Did u found the solution of this? I am also facing same issue.